# Inequalities between powers of PSD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, such that $A \le B$  (where the inequality is understood as having $B - A$ is positive semidefinite. I know that in general,
$A \le B$ does not imply that $A^n \le B^n$. But is there specific conditions such that $A^n \le B^n$ holds?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ can be diagonalized by the same basis of eigenvectors then the conclusion follows. This condition could be too strong ofc.

Answer (score 0):

I will restrict my analysis to the case when $A$ is positive definite, i.e., not singular.

As @daw noticed in the comments, the statement is true for commuting matrices.

Now, let us assume that $A$ and $B$ do not commute, and let $A = U \Lambda U^*$ be an eigendecomposition of $A$ (i.e., $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $U$ is unitary). Then

\begin{align*}
B^n - A^n &= B^n - U \Lambda^n U^* = U \Lambda^{n/2} (\Lambda^{-n/2} U^* B U \Lambda^{-n/2} - {\rm I}) \Lambda^{n/2} U^* \\
&= U \Lambda^{n/2} (\widetilde{B}^n - {\rm I}) (U \Lambda^{n/2})^*,
\end{align*}

where $\widetilde{B} := \Lambda^{-n/2} U^* B U \Lambda^{-n/2}$.

We now see that $B^n - A^n$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $\widetilde{B}^n - {\rm I}$ is such. In turn, this is true if and only if all the eigenvalues of $\widetilde{B}$ are at least $1$.